# How can i see all failed transactions in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When i am trying to analyse result in jmeter it is showing me only failed transactions but that does not give me all transactions.I tried to look into jmeter properties but o luck.Can anybody tell me that how can i see all the transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have enabled the `Errors` checkbox in View Results tree.
Uncheck and try.